# Mockito when and InOrder

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Lets say I have a class:

```
public class A {
  private B mB;
  private C mC;

  public A(B b, C c) {
    mB = b;
    mC = c;
  }

  public void doSomething(D d) {
    mB.doThisFirst(mC);
    if (mB.isValid(d)) {
      mB.doIfValid(mC, d);
    } else {
      mB.doIfNotValid(mC, d);
    }
}
```

Now I'm testing A and make a mock of B and C. I want to do two tests: the first one will assume that mB.isValid(d) is true, while the second one will assume that mB.isValid(d) is false.

How do I verify? I tried stubbing mB.isValid() to return true, but mB.isValid() actually always returns false.

```
private A mA;
private B mB;
private C mC;

@Before public void setup() {
  mB = mock(B.class);
  mC = mock(C.class);
  mA = new A(mB, mC);
}

@Test public void test() {
  d = new D();
  when(mB.isValid(d)).thenReturn(true);
  mA.doSomething(d);

  InOrder inOrder = inOrder(mB);
  inOrder.verify(mB).doThisFirst(mC);
  inOrder.verify(mB).doIfValid(mc, d);
}
```

inOrder.verify(mB).doIfValid(mc, d) will always fail. If I change it to inOrder.verify(mB).doIfNotValid(mc, d), it will pass.

If this is not the correct way to do this, please tell me how. Thanks.

Comment: The test you have (minus few compilation errors) passes for me.

Comment: Yes, it looks OK to me too.  Is `B` final, or does it have any `final` methods?

Comment: D is final, but will that be a problem? Btw I tried using any() in all parameters in when and inOrder, and it passes. Do you guys know why is that?

Comment: That could be related to the `equals` method for `D`.  What you're describing would happen if `d.equals(d)` was false.

Comment: 'd.isValid(d)' will only look at d's value, and decide whether to return true or not. It does not change d's value. Both 'mB.doIfValid(mC, d)' and 'mB.doIfNotValid(mC, d)' modify mC according to values in d, but does not change d.